# How to create custom layer that can pass two inputs and tf.matmul them

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer

the codes of my own model is

```
class KeyQuery(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, v):
        super(KeyQuery, self).__init__()
        self.v = tf.convert_to_tensor(v)
        
    def build(self, input_shape): 
        self.v = tf.Variable(self.v, trainable = True)
        print(self.v.shape)
    def call(self, inputs1, inputs2):
        y1 = tf.matmul(self.v, tf.transpose(inputs1))
        y2 = tf.matmul(y2, inputs2)
        return y2
    
keyquery = KeyQuery(v)

inputs1 = keras.Input(shape=(50,768))
inputs2 = keras.Input(shape=(50,3))
outputs = keyquery(inputs1,inputs2)
model = keras.Model([inputs1,inputs2], outputs)
model.summary()
```

where `v` for `keyquery = KeyQuery(v)` is a 2d array of size (1,768), which can also be seen as a vector.

My ideal situation is that, in
`y1 = tf.matmul(self.v, tf.transpose(inputs1))`, because `self.v.shape` is (1,768), and `inputs1` shape is (50,768), so shape of `y1` should be (1, 50). and shape of `inputs2` is (50,3), so shape of `y2` should be (1, 3).

So when the `inputs1.shape` is (None, 50, 768) and `inputs2.shape` is (None, 50, 3) considering the batch dimension, it should return a result of shape (None, 1, 3). Please note that `keras.Input` does not require batch dimension.

But in real case it returns `ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 768 and 50 for '{{node key_query_4/MatMul}} = BatchMatMulV2[T=DT_FLOAT, adj_x=false, adj_y=false](key_query_4/MatMul/ReadVariableOp, key_query_4/transpose)' with input shapes: [1,768], [768,50,?].`
Because of the batch dimension. I don't know how to fix this for my matrix multiplication.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this with your own layer? we can solve this [`Lambda`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda) layer or other methods.

Comment: @I'mahdi Because I want to train the ```self.v``` vector as I set ```trainable = True``` in ```build``` method. I don't know if I can train ```v``` in Lambda layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider:

1. In The values that pass to the `build_method`, we have the shape of a tensor and in the `call_method` we have the value of the tensor.
2. You need to use `perm` from [tf.transpose()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose) to fix the dimension of the batch and swap other dimensions.

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class KeyQuery(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, v):
        super(KeyQuery, self).__init__()
        self.v = tf.convert_to_tensor(v, dtype='float32')
        
    def build(self, input_shape): # here we have shape of input_tensor
        self.v = tf.Variable(self.v, trainable = True)

    def call(self, inputs): # here we have value of input_tensor
        y1 = tf.matmul(self.v, tf.transpose(inputs[0], perm=[0,2,1]))
        y2 = tf.matmul(y1, inputs[1])
        return y2
    
keyquery = KeyQuery(np.random.rand(1,768))
out = keyquery((tf.random.uniform((25, 50, 768)), tf.random.uniform((25, 50, 3))))
print(out.shape)
# (25, 1, 3)

# or with model
inputs1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(50,768))
inputs2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(50,3))
outputs = keyquery((inputs1,inputs2))
model = tf.keras.Model([inputs1,inputs2], outputs)
model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "model_2"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_13 (InputLayer)          [(None, 50, 768)]    0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_14 (InputLayer)          [(None, 50, 3)]      0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 key_query_27 (KeyQuery)        (None, 1, 3)         768         ['input_13[0][0]',               
                                                                  'input_14[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 768
Trainable params: 768
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```